# how use image slide jquery. i wanted rightarrow is click one image right move and leftarrow is click one image left move

Tags: jquery, css

how use image slide jquery. i wanted right is click one image right move and left is click one image left move  .....

```
       <div class="showrooms clearfix">
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/best-auto.jpg">Best Auto</a> 
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/cheap-car.jpg">Cheap Car</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/cosmo.jpg">Cosmo</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/golden.jpg">Golden</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/ID.jpg">ID</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/kia.jpg">KIA</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/maxano.jpg">MAXANO</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/mmm.jpg">MMM</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/nihon.jpg">Nihon</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/sakura.jpg">Sakura</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/shwe.jpg">Shwe</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/symcar.jpg">SYM</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/theingi.jpg">Theingi</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/thuhtetpyisone.jpg">Thuhtetpyisone</a>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="images/top/uno-korea.jpg">UNO-Korea</a>
            <span class="arrowleft">left</span>
            <span class="arrowright">right</span>
      </div><!-- End Showrooms -->
```

jquery

```
$(".arrowleft").click(function(){
        // i wanted logo image is slide left
});

$(".arrowright").click(function(){
   // i wanted logo image is slide right
});
```

[image]

see http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/cggLe/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic move right/left: http://jsfiddle.net/cggLe/3/ ... no stop, no animation

added an outer container:

```
.container {
    width:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.showrooms {
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    left:0;
}
```

but for fancy results, try a galery plugin, like "Jssor Slider"... just search on Google "jquery gallery"

Answer (score 2):

have you tried this plugin called [flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/carousel-min-max.html) ?

It's very good, can do what you want it to do, is very configurable too. You can set it to move one image at a time, left and right.

To move 1 at a time using the carousel, please follow the setup instructions in the read me file after downloading:

```
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    minItems: 2,
    maxItems: 4,
    move: 1
  });
});
```

The last line in the code above: `move: 1` lets you change the number to how many items you would like to move. For example `move: 2` , or `move: 3` .

Comment: While the answer is correct, you will be severely limited by it's capabilities.